# Why hive partition not work when i using funciton unix_timestamp()

Tags: hive, unix-timestamp, partition

As i know, hive partition can reduce the number of input file if you use the partition column in where clause. For example, in my table t i define a partition named date_entry(type is string, which stores the timestamp).

> select count(*) from t where 
>   date_entry >= (unix_timestamp() - 2 * 24 * 3600) * 1000

I try to execute this query, i expect it will filter some files by the where clause, but it not.
If i don't use function unix_timestamp() , it will work.

Can anybody knows why or give the workaround.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by not working? Doesn't run? Doesn't filter? Does filter, but doesn't take advantage of partitioning? Seeing 'SHOW CREATE TABLE t;' and an example of a query that works without unix_timestamp would be helpful, too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i mean doesn't take advantage of partitioning.
this query will works, select count(*) from t where date_entry >= 1371772800000 .   where 1371772800000 is the result of (unix_timestamp() - 2 * 24 * 3600) * 1000

Comment: I considerd that hive calculate the input path in client side, but the function unix_timestamp() must be in server side. So it did not work. I don't know if i am right.